# Why are new vessels more permeable in microvasculature?

Tags: physiology, human-anatomy, circulatory-system

I know for microvasculature

> New microvasculature (arterioles, venules) are always more permeable
>   as they lack pericytes.

and then I have this sentence about new blood vessels (not specific)

> New vessels contain initially only proliferative endothelium, the basement membrane has not formed yet, and pericytes are absent.

However, I think pericytes are only around microvasculature.

I think the second statement is correct for microvasculature too.

**Why are new vessels more permeable in microasculature?**

Comment: Is there something I'm missing to answer your question?  Perhaps I don't understand the question then.  Otherwise, please accept to help our questions/accepted answers ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In adult/pediatric humans, no they don't.  A good figure to get everyone on the same page was made by [Cleaver & Melton](http://www.nature.com/doifinder/10.1038/nm0603-661):

[image: Comparison of the composition large and small human blood vessels]

It is important to note that:

> In fact, endothelial diversity is reflected by vessel size-specific,
>   organ-specific and even age-specific differences. [(1)](http://www.nature.com/doifinder/10.1038/nm0603-661)

Developing blood vessels in the fetus can be a bit of a different story, and highlights the fact the one should loose the "inert plumbing" mentality of the previous century.  [Modern research](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1235249) tells us that the epithelium is a very dynamic region that participates heavily with signalling.

When large vessels are growing the fetus, [mesenchymal stem cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesenchymal_stem_cell) and [neural crest cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_crest) are the normal precursors to [pericytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pericyte), but depending on exposure the line between pericyte and smooth-muscle cell can be blurred [(2)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1871727/).  I'm assuming it's beyond the scope of the answer to go into the signalling differences.

A good review of [endothelium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothelium) generation, and the surrounding tissue, can be found [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3697817/).

Comment: But think about angiogenesis. There are forming new new vessels in microvasculature which do not have pericytes. I think that should make them more permeable.

Comment: Actually they are going to have at least mesenchymal stem cells recruited before the vessel scaffolding is extended.  You might have the order backwards.  I don't know the permeability difference between full differentiated pericytes and stem cells, but it may not be drastic.  I will see if I can find some lit on the subject, but I'm worried there won't be any.